# How to call an existing Eclipse dialog from my custom Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an Eclipse plugin that need to invoke the Eclipse `Refactor - Move` dialog box and pass the *source file* and *destination location* values dynamically. Since I already have the source file and destination location, I can skip the "Choose destination" page and directly go to the "Preview" page where the user will review the rafactored code caused by the move.

My questions is, how can I call the existing Eclipse dialog from my plugin? What are the extension points should I use?

Comment: The Refactor - Move dialog in does not have from and move values, can you be a bit clearer what you mean here (I'm looking at Eclipse 3.7.2).

Comment: I 'm not exactly sure about the names of the params. But, by from and to, I mean the source file which is to be moved to a new location.

Comment: SO do you actually want to let the user use the UI to select the new location?

Comment: Ah, I see your edit. If you already have the source and the destination why do you want to show the refactor UI, which lets the user choose the destination?

Comment: Well, the user need not change the destination location - so I can very well skip the location selection page and jump to "review" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to activate the **plugin menu spy** in Eclipse. Then open the context menu on one of your classes and select the refactoring menu you are interested in (like Refactor->Move).

Plugin menu spy will show you the related action like `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.MoveAction` which you can click to open and inspect how it invokes the refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just chase the coda that invokes the dialog (e.g. run Eclipse in debugger, set a breakpoint in `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell` ctor and call the action from the pop-up menu).